# WCF service fails to call another WCF service on same machine

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a website hosted in IIS7 in server A. The website calls a web service that is also hosted in server A, but the call returns an error 401. I tried referencing to the web service by IP address, host (A.domain.com), and fully qualified dsn. None worked.

After some research, I found out about the loopback check, and the BackConnectionHostNames.

Refer to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/10/wcf-calling-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis-on-the-same-machine-as-client-throws-an-authentication-error.aspx)

Disabling the loopback check fixes the problem, but is not a desirable solution.

For the BackConnectionHostNames, I tried adding:

- A
- A.domain.com
- A.full.domain.com

But it didn't work.

I played some with IIS http bindings for the website, I tried adding A.domain.com to the host name, and I also tried setting the IP, but still got the same error.

Am I missing something? (I clearly am...) Where else should I be looking at?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to address the service by localhost rather than the dns name.